# Create a unique constraint/index, that considers a second table

Tags: sql, sql-server, unique-constraint, unique-index

In my SQL Server database, I want to create a unique constraint, that considers a second table. My table `ChargeCarrier_Storage` contains the two ID fields `ID_ChargeCarrier` and `ID_Storage`. My `Storage` table contains the two fields `ID` and `ID_StorageType`. The constraint should be, that for storage type `1`, there should be only one possible entry in the `ChargeCarrier_Storage` table. For any other storage type, there can be an infinite number of entries.

My first approach was to create a non-clustered index on the `ChargeCarrier_Storage` table, but that obviously doesn't work, because, as it seems, you can't use joins there.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UQX_OnePickingStoragePerCarrier  
    ON dbo.ChargeCarrier_Storage ccs (ID_ChargeCarrier, ID_Storage)  
    INNER JOIN dbo.Storage s ON s.ID = ccs.ID_Storage
    WHERE s.ID_StorageType = 1;  
GO
```

Is there some easy way to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this on the table, you'll need to use `VIEW` and create the index on there:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

--Create sample tables
CREATE TABLE dbo.ChargeCarrier_Storage (ID_ChargeCarrier int,
                                        ID_Storage int);
CREATE TABLE dbo.Storage (ID int,
                          ID_StorageType int);
GO
--Create Schema bound View
CREATE VIEW dbo.OnePickingStoragePerCarrier WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT ccs.ID_ChargeCarrier,
           s.ID AS ID_Storage
    FROM dbo.ChargeCarrier_Storage ccs
         INNER JOIN dbo.Storage s ON s.ID = ccs.ID_Storage
    WHERE s.ID_StorageType = 1;  
GO
--Create unique (clustered) index
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UQX_OnePickingStoragePerCarrier ON OnePickingStoragePerCarrier (ID_ChargeCarrier,ID_Storage);
GO

--Sample data in Storage
INSERT INTO dbo.Storage (ID,
                         ID_StorageType)
VALUES(1,1),
      (2,1),
      (3,2);
GO

--Tests
INSERT INTO dbo.ChargeCarrier_Storage (ID_ChargeCarrier,
                                       ID_Storage)
VALUES(1,1); --Works
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.ChargeCarrier_Storage (ID_ChargeCarrier,
                                       ID_Storage)
VALUES(2,1); --Works
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.ChargeCarrier_Storage (ID_ChargeCarrier,
                                       ID_Storage)
VALUES(1,2); --Works
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.ChargeCarrier_Storage (ID_ChargeCarrier,
                                       ID_Storage)
VALUES(2,1); --fails due to duplicate
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.ChargeCarrier_Storage (ID_ChargeCarrier,
                                       ID_Storage)
VALUES(1,3); --works.

INSERT INTO dbo.ChargeCarrier_Storage (ID_ChargeCarrier,
                                       ID_Storage)
VALUES(1,3); --works, as not Storage ID 1, so duplicate allowed
GO

GO

DROP VIEW dbo.OnePickingStoragePerCarrier;
DROP TABLE dbo.Storage;
DROP TABLE dbo.ChargeCarrier_Storage;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I already had a similar view with all the required fields. I've added the constraint to this view. I did not know that the restrictions of a view also affect the corresponding tables.

Comment: It's more the constraint of the index that is stopping it @AndréReichelt . When you perform a DML statement against a table all the relevant indexes need to be updated and that includes any indexes on schemabound views as well. As a result, when SQL Server goes to update that index, it finds that an "entry" with the same values is already present and so an error is generated.

Comment: Thank you for your further explanation! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is also ideal scenario for `Instead of Insert and update`.

```
CREATE  TRIGGER trgInsteadOfStorage ON dbo.ChargeCarrier_Storage
INSTEAD OF Insert,Update
AS

BEGIN 
 SET NOCOUNT ON
 if exists(select 1 from dbo.ChargeCarrier_Storage ccs 
 INNER JOIN dbo.Storage s ON s.ID = ccs.ID_Storage
 INNER JOIN inserted i on ccs.ID_ChargeCarrier=i.ID_ChargeCarrier
 and ccs.ID_Storage=i.ID_Storage
 where s.ID_StorageType = 1
 begin
 RAISERROR('Store Type cannot be duplicate',16,1);  
 end
END
```

**Note** :`Trigger code` is untested and is not optimize.Query can be optimize.

After knowing the complete table structure of `ChargeCarrier_Storage`  and understanding how it will be use in search and how many data will be there `inChargeCarrier_Storage` etc.

So it depend upon the situation,in some situation it **might be** beneficial.
Like say If I create one `Non Clustered index` on 
`dbo.ChargeCarrier_Storage (ID_ChargeCarrier)` then I do not have to create one extra Unique Index just for constraint.

Comment: Thank you for your additional approach. The unique index is actually the only index on my view.